# how to generate one html page from partial views

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Let's say I have the folowing class:

```
class Restaraunt
{
 int RestarauntType {get; set;}
 string Address {get; set;}
 string phone {get; set;}
 .....30 more properties
}
```

So, I have a list of Restaraunts and I have blank html forms that have html elements in them.

```
<span class="address"></span>   
<span class="email"></span>
```

Now, I have ~5 different html layouts all are same size.
Depending on the Restaraunt type  I want to pick a template and fill it with info and then take next restaraunt and append it. So I have long html page ready for printing. Here's some pseudo-code that I'm thinking about. Also, open to suggestions on how to do this best.

```
if (restarauntType==1)
{
  var completedForm = GetAndPopulateCsHtmlForm1("/forms/myformNum1.cshtml")
 AppendForm(completedForm)
}
else if (restarauntType==2)
{
....
}
```

Comment: I think I am doing exactly the same thing as you need - I have a list of different tasks and each task ends up with a partial view. In my final report, I join all all the views into one big HTML page. Is that what you want to achive?

Comment: what is your problem

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. I posted an answer, hopefully it's what you want.

Comment: @wapac, yes. That's exactly it

Answer (score 1):

In your main html, try this:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<Restaurant>

@{
    foreach (var restaurant in Model) {
        Html.RenderAction("Child", "Restaurants", restaurant);
    }
}
```

In your `RestaurantsController`:

```
[ChildActionOnly]//optional depending on whether you want to allow rendering this action directly
public ActionResult Child(Restaurant restaurant)
{
    string viewName = //GetYourView depending on your restaurant type
    return PartialView(viewName, restaurant);
}
```

There are many ways to get your view depending on how you determine your partials. You could store your partials in a dictionary indexed by type and access it like this to avoid switch case:

`string viewName = restaurantPartial[restaurant.RestarauntType];`

Then you can have different layouts, for example:

Restaurant1.cshtml

```
@model Restaurant

<span class="address">@Model.Address</span>   
<span class="email">@Model.Email</span>
```

Restaurant2.cshtml:

```
@model Restaurant

<li class="address">@Model.Address</li>   
<li class="email">@Model.Email</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing similar thing. The core of my HTML reporting code is this method that allows me render view into a string:

```
public static string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
  HttpContext context = GetContext();
  HttpContextWrapper httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
  RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
  routeData.Values.Add("controller", "HtmlFake");
  RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData);
  ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, new HtmlFakeController());

  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
    ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
    TempDataDictionary tempData = new TempDataDictionary();
    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View, viewData, tempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controllerContext, viewResult.View);
    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  }
}

public class HtmlFakeController : Controller
{
}
```

With each task I can then do:

```
              object model = GetTaskModel(task.Id);
              string viewData = RenderRazorViewToString(string.Format("~/Views/Task/{0}.cshtml", taskName), model);
```

Finally, I simply use StringBuilder to join views:

```
            sb.Append(viewData);
```